# Assigning Value along with Data Retrieval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to combine assigning a value to a variable and Selecting a column in sql. I need to compute and select a column in a table based on the variable. The variable's value changes based on another column in the table.

var @BeginValue
Columns in table :  ReducedBy

My initial begin value is stored in @BeginValue. The table has reducedBy which is a factor by which my begin value should be reduced. So when i select, beginvalue for the first recored would be @BeginValue and the @EndValue should be @BeginValue = @BeginValue - reducedBy. It continues like this, as many times as the number of records in my table.

Result set must be like this:
@Begin = 10

```
Begin End ReducedBy 
10     8    2
 8     6    2
 6     5    1
```

Is there a way with which i can achieve this without using a cursor or with multiple update statements.

Comment: can you be more clear on your requirements pls

Comment: Can you add more of the query?  How do you determine the order of rows?

Comment: @Andomar : The table has one column ReducedBy which has sequence of numbers.

Comment: One solution which i thought is by having a #table and reading each record in the master table using a cursor and updating the values. But just curious to know whether this could be achieved without using Cursor.

Comment: @Jose: `ReducedBy` does not determine the order of rows.  If the rows are not ordered, there is no way to carry the result from one row to the next.

Comment: In case if i have a primary key column in the table mentioned ?which determines the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign in a query that returns a result set.  The closest you can get is to store the result in a table variable.  Then you can both do computations against that table, and return it as a result set:

```
-- Store results in table variable
declare @tbl table (id int, col1 int, ...)

insert  @tbl
        (id, col1, ...)
select  id
,       col1
,       ...
from    ... your query here ...

-- Assign variable
select  @YourVariable = ... your computation here ...
from    @tbl

-- Return result set
select  *
from    @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is

> Can I do..
>
> ```
> SELECT @a = field, field2 from table
> ```
>
> and get a resultset and set the value of @a?

Then the answer is no, not in a single statement.